# Finding the first non-repeating character in a String using Swift

Tags: swift

This finds the duplicates in the array, but i'm looking for something that finds the first non-repeating character in a string. I've been trying to figure out a way to do this and I cannot figure it out. This is the closest i've gotten.

```
var strArray = ["P","Q","R","S","T","P","R","A","T","B","C","P","P","P","P","P","C","P","P","J"]

println(strArray)

var filter = Dictionary<String,Int>()
var len = strArray.count
for var index = 0; index < len  ;++index {
var value = strArray[index]
if (filter[value] != nil) {
    strArray.removeAtIndex(index--)
    len--
}else{
    filter[value] = 1
}
}
println(strArray)
```

Comment: First non-repeating  or the first repeated ?

Comment: Do You want to identify the "P"?

Comment: I want to find the first character in a string that doesn't repeat. Example: "DEFD -> E"

Comment: ok you have to create a second array and store one by one until you find a duplicate

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus Would that work with the above code? If so could I see an example of something you would change or could you point me in the direction to find the answer? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have added a few other solutions that you might like

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to tell if a character repeats itself, go through the entire array once, incrementing the count of occurrences in a dictionary:

```
let characters = ["P","Q","R","S","T","P","R","A","T","B","C","P","P","P","P","P","C","P","P","J"]

var counts: [String: Int] = [:]
for character in characters {
    counts[character] = (counts[character] ?? 0) + 1
}


let nonRepeatingCharacters = characters.filter({counts[$0] == 1})
// ["Q", "S", "A", "B", "J"]
let firstNonRepeatingCharacter = nonRepeatingCharacters.first!
// "Q"
```

Comment: @mattt Would this also work well if you wanted to find a duplicate integer in an array between 1 and 1,000,000?

Comment: I will try to implement my original idea of doing a find at the array as it goes increasing and I will post it for you so you can compare the speed and pick the fastest one. But i think his solution is probably the fastest one.

Comment: @BradleyScottMaskell I don't see why not. Though, if your problem is constrained to finding duplicate integers in a specific domain, an even more elegant solution would be to create a bit mask, setting the nth bit to 1 for each number `n` in your array. This also has the nice benefit of having the results ordered.

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus There's no avoiding going through the entire array at least once, so any solution will be [`O(n)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). I would expect any speed difference between solutions with similar performance characteristics to be negligible.

Comment: what if the first non-repeating character comes at index 10 and the string is of length 1000?. It is more complex solution in such cases

Comment: How does this preserve order using the dictionary approach? Isn't a dictionary an unordered collection?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple solution

```
let inputString = "PQRSTPRATBCPPPPPCPPJ"

func nonRepeat (_ input: String) -> String {
    for char in input {
        if input.firstIndex(of: char) == input.lastIndex(of: char) {
            return String(char)
        }
    }
    return ""
}
print (nonRepeat(inputString))
```

In the above example it would print "Q"

Answer (score 1):

```
func firstNonRepeatedCharacter(input: String) -> Character?{
    var characterCount : [Character : Int] = [:]
    var uniqueCharacter: Character?

    for character in input{
        if let count = characterCount[character]{
            characterCount[character] = count + 1
            if(uniqueCharacter == character)
            {
                uniqueCharacter = nil
            }
        }
        else{
            characterCount[character] = 1
            if(uniqueCharacter == nil){
                uniqueCharacter = character
            }
        }
    }
    return uniqueCharacter
}
```

Without extra loop to find character from characterCount dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I have found to detect the first non-repeated character. It removes spaces and punctuation to find the actual letter or number that does not repeat.

```
extension String {

func removeNonAlphaNumChars() -> String {
    let charSet = NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet().invertedSet

    return self
        .componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(charSet)
        .joinWithSeparator("")
}

var firstNonRepeatedCharacter: Character? {
    let alphaNumString = self.removeNonAlphaNumChars()

    let characters = alphaNumString.characters
    let count = characters.count
    guard count > 0 else { return nil }

    // Find unique chars
    var dict: [Character: Int?] = [:]
    for (index, char) in characters.enumerate() {
        if dict[char] != nil {
            dict[char] = (nil as Int?)
        }
        else {
            dict[char] = index
        }
    }

    return dict.filter { $0.1 != nil }.sort { $0.1 < $1.1 }.first?.0
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I totally wonder why the accepted answer was considered correct. They are using

```
.first
```

method of a dictionary and that according to documentation would return a random element in the dictionary and not the first element as a dictionary in swift is not ordered like an array.
[image: check the image to see dictionary as an unordered collection]

please do find below an implementation that works

```
func firstNonRepeatingLetter(_ str: String)  -> String{
   var characterDict = [String : Int]()

   for character in str{
       let lower = character.lowercased()
       if let count = characterDict[lower]{
         characterDict[lower] = count + 1
       }else{
        characterDict[lower] = 1
       }
   }

   let filtered = characterDict.filter { $0.value == 1}
   for character in str{
       let lower = character.lowercased()
       if let _ = filtered[lower]{
        return lower
       }
   }

   return ""
}


firstNonRepeatingLetter("moonmen") would return "e".
```

Answer (score 0):

We can iterate once and keep the letter counts inside a dictionary.
Then, iterate again and return first letter where we see it was encountered once only (or "_" if not found a non-repeating letter):

```
func firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s: String) -> Character {
    var letterCounts: [String: Int] = [:]
    var result: Character = "_"

    for letter in s {
        if let currentLetterCount = letterCounts[String(letter)] {
            letterCounts[String(letter)] = currentLetterCount + 1
        } else {
            letterCounts[String(letter)] = 1
        }
    }

    for letter in s {
        if letterCounts[String(letter)] == 1 {
            result = letter
            break
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[OrderedDictionary](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections/blob/main/Documentation/OrderedDictionary.md) makes this easy for all `Sequence`s of `Hashable`s, not just `String`s:

```swift
import struct OrderedCollections.OrderedDictionary

extension Sequence where Element: Hashable {
  var firstUniqueElement: Element? {
    OrderedDictionary(zip(self, true)) { _, _  in false }
      .first(where: \.value)?
      .key
  }
}
```

```swift
/// `zip` a sequence with a single value, instead of another sequence.
public func zip<Sequence: Swift.Sequence, Constant>(
  _ sequence: Sequence, _ constant: Constant
) -> LazyMapSequence<
  LazySequence<Sequence>.Elements,
  (LazySequence<Sequence>.Element, Constant)
> {
 sequence.lazy.map { ($0, constant) }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
func getFirstUniqueChar(string:String)->Character?{
var counts: [String: Int] = [:]
for character in string {
    let charString = "\(character)"
    counts[charString] = (counts[charString] ?? 0) + 1
}
let firstNonRepeatingCharacter = string.first {counts["\($0)"] == 1}
return firstNonRepeatingCharacter
}

print(getFirstUniqueChar(string: string))
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import Foundation
import Glibc
var str:String = "aacbbcee"//your input string
var temp:String = ""
var dict:[Character:Int] = [:]

for char in str{
    if let count = dict[char]{
        dict[char] = count+1//storing values in dict and incrmenting counts o key
    }
    else{
        dict[char] = 0
    }
}
var arr:[Character] = []
for (key, value) in dict{
    if value == 0{
        arr.append(key)//filtering out, take characters which has value>0
    }  //int(arr)
}//print(arr.count)
if arr.count != 0{
outer:for char in str{//outer is labeling the loop
    for i in arr{
        if i == char{
        print(i,"is first")//matching char with array elements if found break
        break outer
        }
        else{
            continue
        }
    }
}
}
else{
print("not found")
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
func firstNonRepeatedChar(string: String) -> Character {
var arr: [Character] = []
var dict: [Character : Int] = [:]

for character in string.description {
    arr.append(character)
}

for character in arr {
    dict[character] = (dict[character] ?? 0) + 1
}
let nonRepeatedArray = arr.filter { char in
    if dict[char] == 1 {return true}
    return false
}
let firstNonRepeatedChar = nonRepeatedArray.first
return firstNonRepeatedChar! 
}
print(firstNonRepeatedChar(string: "strinstrig"))
```