# Ordering of Dictionary Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm trying to work through a problem at the moment which is currently doing the rounds on the internet. The problem is: Given an array of characters, find the first non repeating character. I had a go at it and solved it but I was curious about how other people solved it so I did some looking around and found this answer:

```
let characters = ["P","Q","R","S","T","P","R","A","T","B","C","P","P","P","P","P","C","P","P","J"]

var counts: [String: Int] = [:]
for character in characters {
    counts[character] = (counts[character] ?? 0) + 1
}

let nonRepeatingCharacters = characters.filter({counts[$0] == 1})

let firstNonRepeatingCharacter = nonRepeatingCharacters.first!
print(firstNonRepeatingCharacter) //"Q"
```

Source: [Finding the first non-repeating character in a String using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338045/finding-the-first-non-repeating-character-in-a-string-using-swift)

What I don't understand about this solution, is why it always returns Q, when there are other elements "S" "A" "B" and "J" that could be put first when the filter is applied to the dictionary. My understanding of dictionaries is that they are unordered, and when you make one they change from run to run. So if I make one:

```
let dictionary:[String:Int] = ["P": 9, "C": 8, "E": 1]
```

And then print 'dictionary', the ordering will be different. Given this, can anyone explain why the solution above works and maintains the order in which the dictionary elements were added?

Comment: I'm not sure if you read my question.

Comment: The output is the first non-repeating element from `characters`, which is an **array.** The order of the key/value pairs in the dictionary `counts` is irrelevant.

Comment: @vacawama Type inferred `reduce(into: [:])`

Comment: @LeoDabus, I did try that and got an error, but I must have changed something else in the interim, because that does work.

Comment: Concisely: `let counts = characters.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1, default: 0] += 1 };print(characters.first { counts[$0] == 1 } ?? "none found")`.  Note: Use `characters.first` instead of `characters.filter` because `first` will quit when it finds one instead of filtering the entire array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not looking correctly at the code. The filter is not applied to a dictionary. It is applied to the array (`characters`), which has a defined order. The dictionary is used only to store counts.